i'm not able to create connect account on stripe connect
I'm trying to create a stripe onboarding controller in the node.js but I'm getting the following error You cannot accept the Terms of Service on behalf of Standard and Express connected accounts.
    const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
      type: "express",
      country: country,
      business_type: "individual",
      business_profile: {
        //may need to update this in the production || current Professional Services
        mcc: "8999",
        url: "https://www.developerbazaar.com/",
        name: user.firstName + " " + user.lastName,
        product_description: "Professional Services",
        url: "https://www.developerbazaar.com/",
      },
      email: user.email,
      capabilities: {
        transfers: { requested: true },
      },
      tos_acceptance: {
        service_agreement: country === "US" ? "full" : "recipient",
        date: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
        ip: req.ip,
        user_agent: req.headers["user-agent"],
      },
      settings: {
        //update this in the production
        branding: {
          icon: "https://www.developerbazaar.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Developer-Bazaar-Logo.svg",
          logo: "https://www.developerbazaar.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Developer-Bazaar-Logo.svg",
          primary_color: "#000000",
          secondary_color: "#ff0000",
        },
      },
    });


The error message is pretty explanatory. You can't do this, so you need to remove the tos_acceptance:{...} you're trying to pass.
